# Perl Curses::UI window doesn't draw all widgets

Tags: perl, user-interface, curses

I'm using perl's Curses::UI to build a ui for a fairly simple script.  However, not everything I add to a window is being drawn.  Only two things get drawn, the first widget added, and whatever the first widget to get focus is.  Executing the code below, only the first TextViewer and then the button are drawn.  The 2nd and 3rd TextViewers (for both Windows) aren't drawn.  If I make them focusable, and then tab to them, they get drawn.  What am I doing wrong?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use Curses::UI;

my $cui = new Curses::UI;

my $win = $cui->add(
   'window','Window',
   -border  => 1,
   -title   => 'Test Big Window'
);
$win->add(
   'test0','TextViewer',
   -x => 1,
   -y => 1,
   -text => 'test0',
   -focusable  => 0
);
$win->add(
   'test1','TextViewer',
   -x => 1,
   -y => 2,
   -text => 'test1',
   -focusable  => 0
);
$win->add(
   'test2','TextViewer',
   -x => 1,
   -y => 3,
       -text => 'test2',
   -focusable  => 0
);
$win->add(
   'winButtons','Buttonbox',
   -x => 1,
   -y => 4,
   -buttons => [{-label=>'sub_window',-onpress=>sub{show_win2($win);}}]
);

sub show_win2 {
    $win = shift;
    my $win2 = $win->add(
       'window2','Window',
       -border  => 1,
       -title   => 'Test Little Window',
       -centered   => 1,
       -height  => 20,
       -width   => 40
    );
    $win2->add(
       'test3','TextViewer',
       -x => 1,
       -y => 1,
       -text => 'test3',
       -focusable  => 0
    );
    $win2->add(
       'test4','TextViewer',
       -x => 1,
       -y => 2,
       -text => 'test4',
       -focusable  => 0
    );
    $win2->add(
       'test5','TextViewer',
       -x => 1,
       -y => 3,
       -text => 'test5',
       -focusable  => 0
    );
    my $buttons = $win2->add(
       'addOutputButtons','Buttonbox',
       -buttonalignment  => 'right',
       -bg               => -1,
       -fg               => -1,
       -y                => 4,
       -buttons          => [{-label=>'Exit',-onpress=>sub{exit(0);}}]
    );
    $win2->modalfocus();
}

$cui->mainloop();
$win->modalfocus();
```

P.S. Is there an easier way to insert code blocks like that, besides manually adding 4 spaces before each line??

Comment: Enter your code, select it, then click the code formatting button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `TextEntry` with `-readonly => 1` option instead of `TextViewer` as a workaround  to display the text elements.

At least it works for me.

```
...
$win->add(
   'test1','TextEntry',
   -x => 1,
   -y => 2,
   -text => 'test1',
   -readonly => 1,
   -focusable => 0,
);
...
```

Comment: This does work.  I ended up just using Label as it supports multiple lines as well.

Answer (score 0):

First widget is overlapping other widgets. Fix each widget height and width and make sure that no widget overlaps other widget's space. Make sure x and y parameters are also set correctly to avoid overlapping.